# Delphi to Visual basic conversion utility

Tags: vb.net, delphi

Is there any code conversion tool for converting Delphi to Visual Basic? Please advice.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I seriously doubt it, most people went the other way. Do you want VB6 or VB.Net?

Comment: Can you provide more details - what version of Delphi is the original application written in and what version of Visual Basic are you targeting?

Comment: It is inspiring to see how all posters so far have managed to mostly resist the urge to ask why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Not that I'm ware of. There are tools to convert Delphi to C# or Visual Basic to Delphi. But not the other way around. It's probably because Delphi has a lot more features then Visual Basic to make it a difficult transition.

You can do it by hand. But it'll take a while.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider moving to VB.NET (and .NET platform in general butnot VB6), these questions might give you some ideas/options:

- [What tools exist to convert a Delphi 7 application to C# and the .Net framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59547/what-tools-exist-to-convert-a-delphi-7-application-to-c-and-the-net-framework)?
- [Is there an easy way, to Port a Win32 App in Delphi 2009 to .NET ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132299/is-there-an-easy-way-to-port-a-win32-app-in-delphi-2009-to-net)
- [Migrating a Delphi 7 application to .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207169/migrating-a-delphi-7-application-to-net)
- [Delphi to .NET + C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237715/delphi-to-net-c)
- [Delphi’s interoperability with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595601/delphis-interoperability-with-net)

You can try migrating the application from Delphi (Win32) to [Delphi.NET](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio) or [Delphi Prism](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-prism)
Once this step is complete you can consider migrating to VB.NET or C#

But it really depends on the technologies used by your original application (e.g. BDE, 3rd party components), level of interaction with WinApi and so on.

Comment: actually - if it's Delphi.NET and must be converted to VB.NET, then just use the .Net Reflector on the compiled code.

Answer (score 2):

[Delux Software](http://www.deluxsoftware.com/) has one.

Comment: I must be missing something there Rob - I can see translators to go the other way, but nothing VB to Delphi on the linked page. (I was intrigued, sue me!)

Comment: Quite right, I read the question as "VB to Delphi" not the other way around :o)